# Set the width of the columns with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the width of the columns/cells in a table. I've set the td element through pseudo selectors, because I have a lot of rows and I don't want to repeat.  But this doesn't work. Each cell is always the same width. This is what I've tried and what it takes more sense to me. And I need the last of three.

```
<table class="table-accordion">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Sofia</td> 
    <td>50</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>50</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

This is the css

```
th {
  background-color: $primary-color;
  color: $white;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 3%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  width: 5%;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 47.5%;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 15.8%;
}

td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 15.8%;
}

td:last-child {
  width: 15.8%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `column-width` instead of `width` in the css.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width for more details.

Comment: That hasn't worked for me. What it has worked is setting a colgroup and giving a width to each column. But thank you¡¡

Answer (score 0):

you shouls care that all widths add up to 100% and you have to especify the width of the table, in percents or pixels:

```
th {
  background-color: $primary-color;
  color: $white;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 3%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:100%;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20%;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
}

td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 10%;
}

td:last-child {
  width: 10%;
}
```